# Показать все атрибуты в селекторе при добавлении товара WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, атрибуты

При добавлении нового товара, на вкладке атрибутов в селекторе показывает только часть атрибутов. У меня их около 70, а показывает, дай бог 20-30.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как можно показать все атрибуты в этом селекторе?

Comment: Не представляю какому товару может понадобится столько атрибутов  (соответственно никогда не делал), но почти уверен - если сделать вывод всех - это будет тормозить. Поэтому там есть быстрый фильтр - набирай несколько букв названий и получишь нужное.

Comment: Так быть не должно. Или с атрибутами проблема или ... смотри логи ошибок (в тч и якса)

Comment: Извините, точнее проблема в том, что при наборе нескольких первых букв, находит только видимое. А если скопировать все название атрибута и вставить, например 2-3 слова, тогда находит и его.